# Selecting a schema in Snowflake Snowsight

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

we dipped our toes in Snowsight today for the first time. The features look very promising!

However, we don't manage to configure a schema for the entire worksheet (only role, warehouse and database). Also using `USE SCHEMA sc1;` doesn't seem to do the trick.

This is annoying since it means we would need to fully qualify every single statement with a database.schema prefix.

Does anyone have a more comfy solution to this? Is it maybe a shortcoming due to the fact that you can for now only execute one query at a time?

Help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think what you have there should work. So if you just execute the USE SCHEMA statement, what would you get? You should have something like "Statement executed successfully".

And then you shouldn't need to use the fully qualify table name from then onward.

Hope this help, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Executing `USE SCHEMA xyz;` does set your context to that schema.  You can see this by running a `SELECT current_schema();` command.

That said, it is worth providing your feedback to Snowflake.  This is a new interface and has a lot of features that still need to be implemented.  Customer feedback goes a long way!

Answer (score 0):

It worked after executing the statements one by one.
So first the `USE SCHEMA abc;` and only *then* my actual SELECT statement.

I hope multiple SQL statements in a single call will soon be possible. Until then Snowsight is only usable on an experimental basis.

Thank you for your replies!